# Hg: How to fold local commits in the middle of the stack

Tags: mercurial

Simple question:
Let's say I have local commits like following:

```
master -> a -> b -> c
```

I want to merge a and b. What is the hg command for this? I tried

```
hg up b
hg fold -r a
```

got an error saying: `abort: cannot fold chain not ending with a head or with branching`

I tried

```
hg up b
hg amend
```

This created a stack like

```
master -> a.preamend -> b -> c
                     \-> a
```

which doesn't allow me to continue on c. Finally, I tried

```
hg up b
hg histedit a
abort: can only histedit a changeset together with all its descendants
```

No luck. What I want is something like:

```
hg up b
hg *merge* -r a
```

returns

```
master -> b -> c
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

**About error message**

This error message saying `abort: cannot fold chain not ending with a head or with branching` occurs when new unstable changes are not allowed in your repository.

Unstable changes are those obsolete changes whose children(s) are not obsolete. You should look for `experimental.evolution` in `hg config` and add `"unstable"` to it.

**About folding changesets**

There are two ways to fold commits in the middle of stack using `fold`.

1. Use `--exact` option : You can do `hg fold -r a -r b --exact`. In this it does not matter what is the parent of your working directory is. You have to mention the revisions to be folded.
2. Update to the last child which you want to prune, in this case it is `b`, using `hg update -r b`. Then run `hg fold -r a`. The revision passed to fold must be the initial revision of the chain which you want to fold.

You had

`master -> a -> b -> c`

You folded `a` and `b`, they became obsolete, since `b` has a child `c` which is not obsolete, it is an unstable changeset.

So what you are doing is not wrong, it's just not allowed according to your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to squash the changes from two commits in to one commit then, you can use hg rebase command to squash the changes.

> $ hg rebase -r a::b -d master --collapse

this will squash the changes of both a and b commits in to one commit

for more info refer to: [RebaseExtension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RebaseExtension)

Comment: Should I hg update/checkout to b or a before running this?

Comment: you have to update and checkout master branch before running this, since a and b are commits you need not checkout a or b

Comment: This gives an error:
`abort: can't remove original changesets with unrebased descendants`
`(use --keep to keep original changesets)`

Comment: As stated, you can use the --keep option. The newly created squashed changeset will then be created and the original changesets will be kept in a separate branch. If the rebase was successful, you can then rebase everything that is on top of the original changesets over onto the squashed changeset. Once this is done the original changesets can be stripped.